# .htaccess 301 redirect in some case

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a rewrite rule for this problem. If the subdomain NOT starts with 's' OR 'img1' OR 'img2' ... 'img9' redirect to an other domain with subdomain.

Example:

```
http://any.aaaa.com -> http://any.bbbb.com
```

but no redirect:

```
http://s.aaaa.com
http://img1.aaaa.com
```

This is what I tried, but doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(s|img.).aaaa.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.bbbb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).aaaa.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(s|img.).aaaa.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.bbbb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```